# get specific object in array

Tags: angular, typescript

I got problem to get specific object in array.

Example array

[image]

I just want `id`

**Code**

```
for (let item of this.commonService.popularList$.getValue()) {
        console.log(item['menuList'])
}
```

if I add code like this `console.log(item['menuList'][id])` it display like this `undefined`

Comment: Probably meant `item['menuList'][0]['id']` or even `item['menuList'][0].id` (unless I misunderstood something)

Comment: if I add [0] it just select one and if more than one? what should I do?-

Comment: Is `popularList$` on `Observable`? That's usually what the `$` suffix indicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If item['menuList'] is an array of objects then you need to put in the index as well

```
for (let item of this.commonService.popularList$.getValue()) {
    console.log(item['menuList'])
    for(let i=0; i<item['menuList'].length; i++){
         console.log(item['menuList'][i]['id']);//will print the ids
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears you're accessing an array of objects.

Given the following:

```
const arr = [{ id: 12 }, { id: 57 }];
```

You can access the objects by index and then retrieve the array, the following example will provide you the id of the first item in the list (adjust 0 to whichever index you desire.)

```
arr[0].id
```

Or you could map the array to an array of simply  ids like such...

```
arr.map(({ id }) => id)
```

Which would return a new array, in this example, this would equal:

```
[12, 57]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let idArray = [];
for (let item of this.commonService.popularList$.getValue()) {
     if(item && item['menuList'] && Array.isArray(item['menuList']))
       item['menuList'].forEach(menu => idArray.push(menu.id));
}
 console.log(idArray)
```

Test code

```
let data = [{menuList:[{id:1},{id:2}]},{menuList:[{id:3},{id:4}]}];
let idArray = [];
for (let item of data) {
    if(item && item['menuList'] && Array.isArray(item['menuList']))
       item['menuList'].forEach(menu => idArray.push(menu.id));
}
console.log(idArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `this.commonService.popularList$` is an RxJS `BehaviorSubject`, using its `GetValue()`/`value` members may not be desirable because we will not receive any new values that are published by the `BehaviorSubject`.

Therefore, I will suggest an alternative to what has been suggested so far.

```
this.commonService.popularList$.subscribe(popularList => {
  for (const item of popularList) {
    console.log(item.id);
  }
});
```

This means we will always print the latest values as they come in.

Answer (score 2):

For retrieve the id that you want, just do the following:

```
const arr = [{ id: 9 }, { id: 15 }, { id: 18 }, { id: 25 }];
const specificId = 18;
const yourId = arr.find(({id}) => id === specificId);

console.log(yourId)
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-peijbp) of how it works.